# Can we enable special Accounts to be shared with multiple roles/public groups?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

We're looking to have Salesforce configured that each role represents a business unit (e.g. Colorado Offices). Some special accounts require that multiple business units own/manage the account. For example, if Colorado and Quebec are both active with ACME Arcitects, we want each business unit/role to see it equally rather than just one of them.

Right now, we've solved the issue of single role ownership just by having sharing rules based on the owner of the Account. So if an Owner belongs to the Colordado offices business unit then everyone in that business unit gets the same access to that Account.

We've looked at Public Groups but haven't figured out a way to sidestep our problem. We're open to anything. Not sure if Account Teams lets us solve this either since it's a user-by-user basis.

Our end goal is that most Accounts can be seen/managed by a single business unit but that some Accounts may be seen/managed by multiple business units.

Comment: Have you looked at Enterprise Territory Management?

Comment: ETM might be right answer here but Account Team(s) are certainly easier. With ATeams, you'll have to automate add/remove of members via your favorite option in SF (Flow, triggers, etc).

Comment: And what about manual sharing using the role's generated sharing group?

Comment: @DanielHoechst I have but I think it doesn't appear to be a scalable solution. If I understand that concept, it requires choosing individuals rather than roles or public groups.

Comment: @identigral Teams seems to be a decent choice. I'd prefer something a little cleaner. What we're considering is using public groups instead that either represent multiple BU's or represent a single special Account. Neither solution is great but should do the job if we need to fall back.

Comment: @PhilW Role's generated sharing group? Is there a screenshot or article on this concept? I'm not sure I understand.